How not to perform rounding from float to torch.float64
I want to convert a list of floats into a tensor. How can I do it without rounding being performed?
tensor = torch.tensor(res, dtype=torch.float64)

# res:[-0.5479744136460554, -0.5555555555555556, -1.0]
# currently tensor = [tensor([-0.5480, -0.5556, -1.0000], dtype=torch.float64)


# goal tensor = [tensor([-0.5479744136460554, -0.5555555555555556, -1.0], dtype=torch.float64)


I solved. It's just a printing precision issue, it hasn't actually been rounded. To see it in full, use the command:
torch.set_printoptions(precision=16)

